# Linking to static assets, custom MVC application (PHP)

Tags: css, .htaccess, assets

In my `.htaccess` file, I redirect all request to my `public/index.php` file.

From there I do routing, based on params given in `URL`.

Problem is with my `css` file being included in `view`, which says `href="css/app.css"`. All works good when specifying request like `http://hostname/public/something`, but If I go one directory deeper, like say for example:
`http://hostname/public/something/else`, my css breaks.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using **relative** paths instead of **absolute** paths for all your html links (images, javascript, css, href links).

Actually, your rule can create virtual directories.

Let's say you have css links that way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

For some examples, here is the path resolution

- `/public/something` -> */public/css/style.css* (**GOOD**)
- `/public/something/else` -> */public/something/css/style.css* (**WRONG**)

To avoid that behaviour, use **absolute** path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css">
```

Or, if you don't want to change all your html links, you can add this line after `<head>` html tag

```
<base href="/public/">
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction, what confused me, is that I tried with `/public/` and it didn't work, but the real problem was, that I am serving this from `userdir` when develooping locally, so what I had to do at the end, is specifying path as `/~myusername/path/to/project/public/css/app.css`.

Comment: In my answer, i used `/public/` since that's what you wrote in your question. But it could be something else, like you said. You must use path to your project if that's easy for you to understand. For example, in local, you can have your project in `/xxx/yyy/my/project/` then you will have `/xxx/yyy/my/project/` as absolute path since you can reach your project with `http://localhost/xxx/yyy/my/project/`

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute links like `href="/public/css/app.css"`.

If the `/public` part is variable, e.g. between your development machine and the production server, then use a variable or constant:

```
<?php echo ROOT_URL . '/css/app.css'; ?>
```

The most useful thing to do is typically to create a small helper function for that:

```
<?php echo css('app.css'); ?>
```

Depending on what kind of templating system you may be using, this could look as nice as this:

```
{{ css 'app.css' }}
```

Comment: I am not using any templating system, it is simple MVC that I began from scratch, as this is somewhat small project. I will try to implement something like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a global variable or constant or some functions to you PHP application named: $site_root, that is a path to your root directory. For example CodeIgniter does this with url_helper, See This: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html 
Then add $siteRoot before your css file

```
... href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/link/to/your/file.css" ...
```